# Android , Deserialize JSON Array that have different types using Jackson

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, jackson

I have an Android application that uses Jackson to deserialize the data and I face troubles in creating the pojo for this json string:

```
{
    "response": [{
        "view": "ticker",
        "items": []
    }, {
        "view": "note",
        "note": "This is a note"
    }, {
        "wn": "bla",
        "sd": "bla bla",
        "tf": 28,
        "rh": 22,
        "ws": 9,
        "ti": "14:00",
        "view": "hbhi"
    }]
}
```

I create the following pojos:

**TickerModel.java**

```
public class TickerModel implements Serializable {

@JsonProperty("view")
private String view ;

@JsonProperty("items")
private String items;


public String getView() {
    return view;
}

public void setView(String view) {
    this.view = view;
}

public String getItems() {
    return items;
}

public void setItems(String items) {
    this.items = items;
}
```

}

**NoteModel.java**

```
public class NoteModel implements Serializable {

@JsonProperty("view")
private String view ;

@JsonProperty("note")
private String note;

public String getView() {
    return view;
}

public void setView(String view) {
    this.view = view;
}

public String getNote() {
    return note;
}

public void setNote(String note) {
    this.note = note;
}
```

}

any ideas on how to to do deserialize this JSON using Jackson?

Answer (score 0):

> first validate json using [this](http://jsonlint.com/).

And create pojo classes using [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) or [this](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/)

Answer (score 0):

No need to create two separate pojo's, you can have pojo like below -

```
public class Response {

@JsonProperty("view")
private String view;
@JsonProperty("items")
private List<Object> items = new ArrayList<Object>();
@JsonProperty("note")
private String note;
@JsonProperty("wn")
private String wn;
@JsonProperty("sd")
private String sd;
@JsonProperty("tf")
private Integer tf;
@JsonProperty("rh")
private Integer rh;
@JsonProperty("ws")
private Integer ws;
@JsonProperty("ti")
private String ti;
//setters //getters 
}
```

Note: Since items is an array in your json, you should map it with array-list of type objects. Also you can get pojo's craeted online if you have json data - http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/